# Using InfoPath form on document creation to set metadata

Tags: sharepoint-2010, infopath2010

I have a document library in SharePoint with a custom content type (Title, Responsible Employee, Cost - that kind of thing), and I'd like to force a user to set these fields when a document is saved in the library.

Ideally I'd like to be able to design an InfoPath form that pops up when a user creates/uploads a document. Is this possible? Or, is there another way to do this?